# Is there a way to trigger cloud data fusion pipeline form local via python?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

I am trying to build a code in which i need to trigger the cloud data fusion pipeline from a desktop based app which is i am building. It is currently on python. Can anyone suggest a way to initiate pipeline without using the google cloud data fusion UI and with some lines of python code.

Comment: For that purpose you can use CDAP Rest API, more info [here](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/reference/cdap-reference).

Comment: If you found answers below relevant to you needs, then consider to [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) community contributors efforts or/and [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the most useful one in order to properly address the future users researching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find either [PycURL](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/quickstart.html#) library approaching [cURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) client side HTTP methods sender or [Requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) that can be used to trigger calls to the mentioned CDAP REST API inventory from Python code.

The example below shows Python code, affording HTTP `POST` method for [starting](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/reference/cdap-reference#start_a_batch_pipeline)
batch pipeline within `PyCurl`, for reference I used the same environmental variables as per documentation [link](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/reference/cdap-reference) mentioned by @Edwin Elia:

Set up environment variables:

`export AUTH_TOKEN=$(gcloud auth print-access-token)`

```
export CDAP_ENDPOINT=$(gcloud beta data-fusion instances describe \
--location=<region> \
--format="value(apiEndpoint)" \
${INSTANCE_ID})v3/namespaces/namespace-id/apps/pipeline-name/workflows/DataPipelineWorkflow/start
```

Python code snippet:

```
import pycurl
import os

CDAP_ENDPOINT = os.environ['CDAP_ENDPOINT']
AUTH_TOKEN = os.environ['AUTH_TOKEN']

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, CDAP_ENDPOINT)
c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ['Authorization: Bearer %s' %(AUTH_TOKEN)])
c.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
c.perform()
```

Comment: this code snippet is not working, not giving any error neither completing.

Comment: Did you try to use the other CDAP [HTTP RESTful API](https://docs.cdap.io/cdap/current/en/reference-manual/http-restful-api/index.html#cdap-http-restful-api-v3) methods within this script?

Answer (score 0):

To complement / join both answers above. To run in the command line, you can use curl for the HTTP request:

```
> export AUTH_TOKEN=$(gcloud auth print-access-token)
> export REGION=your-region
> export INSTANCE_ID=your-instance
> export PIPELINE=your-pipeline
> export NAMESPACE=your-namespace

> export CDAP_ENDPOINT=$(gcloud beta data-fusion instances describe \
    --location=${REGION} \
    --format="value(apiEndpoint)" \
  ${INSTANCE_ID})

> curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ${AUTH_TOKEN}" --request POST "${CDAP_ENDPOINT}/v3/namespaces/${NAMESPACE}/apps/${PIPELINE}/workflows/DataPipelineWorkflow/start"
```

A fully Python solution, without needed to use the command line would be:

```
import requests
import os

# Set environment variables
AUTH_TOKEN = os.popen('gcloud auth print-access-token').read().strip()
REGION = 'your-region'
PIPELINE = 'your-pipeline_name'
NAMESPACE = 'your_namespace'
INSTANCE_ID = 'your-instance-id'

# CDAP endpoint of the instance
CDAP_ENDPOINT = os.popen('gcloud beta data-fusion instances describe --location=' +
                         REGION + ' --format="value(apiEndpoint)" ' + INSTANCE_ID).read().strip()

# Send post request
response = requests.post(CDAP_ENDPOINT + "/v3/namespaces/" + NAMESPACE + "/apps/" + PIPELINE + "/workflows/DataPipelineWorkflow/start",
                        headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + AUTH_TOKEN})
```

Make sure you are authenticated to run these commands, and for that, as pointed out, consult the documentation : https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/reference/cdap-reference

Answer (score -1):

As @mk_sta mentioned in the commend, Cloud Data Fusion pipelines can be triggered using REST API, specifically:

```
POST -H "Authorization: Bearer ${AUTH_TOKEN}" "${CDAP_ENDPOINT}/v3/namespaces/<namespace-id>/apps/<pipeline-name>/workflows/DataPipelineWorkflow/start"
```

You can refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/reference/cdap-reference) for more information.